# The calculation model of the loan at a pre- agreed installments

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help if anyone knows and has the will to extract the factor $r$ of the equation to the left side: 
$$\begin{align*}
&a=C \frac{r^n(r-1)}{r^n-1},\\
\implies & r=?????
\end{align*}$$
I was trying to simplify expressions with the assumption that the factors $r$ , $n$ is greater than zero , unfortunately I do not have a better idea.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation takes the following algebraic form
$$
C X^{n+1}-(a+C) X^{n}+a= 0 \tag1
$$ then you may use a *numerical algorithm* (using for example [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)) to find a numerical approximation of the *apropriate* root ($0<X<2, \, X \neq1$) since when $n$ is great ($n \geq 5$), there is no  *general finite formula in terms of radicals of the coefficients* above for the solution.